# How can I convert OpenBUGS Coda file to mcmc object in R?

Tags: r, bayesian, mcmc, winbugs, r2winbugs

I used OpenBUGS and it produced coda files of MCMC output. To calculate and plot Gelman Rubin and Geweke diagnostics, I need to convert this coda.odc file to a mcmc object in R? Is there any way to do this? Or do you recommend me some other way(s) to do this analysis?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ues `read.coda` in the [coda](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/coda/) package,... something like:

```
library(coda)
my.coda <- read.coda("Chain1.txt", "CODAIndex.txt")
```

Might work with .odc files. Defiantly works if you save the CODA files as .txt from OpenBUGS
The `my.coda` will be a `mcmc` type object.